# Sum of columns of dataframe based on time period in R

Tags: r, sum

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and and multiple rows. The data is based on monthly observations over the period of 11 years. Now I want to take the sum of each column based on observations for previous 12 months. For example sum of column for Jan-05 is based on its observations from Jan-04 to Dec-04. And for Feb-05 is based on observations from Feb-04 to Jan-05 and so on. My original data frame has data for 10 years and monthly data.
I illustrate part of my dataframe as follows:

```
df1
Month   A        B      C
Jan-04  0.003   0.006   NA
Feb-04  0.003   0.002   NA
Mar-04  -0.005  -0.001  NA
Apr-04  0.000   0.000   NA
May-04  0.000   -0.002  NA
Jun-04  -0.001  -0.001  NA
Jul-04  -0.001  -0.001  NA
Aug-04  -0.010  NA      NA
Sep-04  0.001   NA      NA
Oct-04  0.002   NA      NA
Nov-04  -0.003  NA      NA
Dec-04  -0.003  NA      NA
Jan-05  0.005  -0.002   NA
Feb-05  -0.0015 0.004   0.0003
Mar-05  -0.0041 0.002   0.0070
```

The desired resultant dataframe

```
Month   A        B      C
Jan-05  -0.013  0.004   NA
Feb-05  -0.011  -0.004  NA
Mar-05  -0.0151 -0.0014 0.0003
```

Comment: Have tried anything yourself or did search similar questions on SO?

Comment: @danas.zuokas I have but unfortunately nothing similar to tge scenerio I have presented.

Comment: Try `library(zoo);library(data.table); na.omit(setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) lag(rollapply(x, 12, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)))), .SDcols= A:C])`

Comment: @Aquarius just change it to the initial column name : final column name (if it is in sequence) or just use the index of column numbers

Comment: @akrun it works perfect now but only one thing for a time period(12 months) if there are all NAs I receive sum for that as Zero but I require it to return NA I tried `is.na(df) <- df == 0` but receive `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  invalid time series parameters specified`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in base R. First we define a function to subset the df based on the time difference from the date of interest and find the column sums on that subsetted df, and then we run that function for all of the time points of interest.

```
subset_last_year <- function(df, date, cols_to_sum = c("A", "B", "C")){
  date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d-%b-%y")
  df$Time_Difference = difftime(date, df$Month_Date, units = "weeks")
  df_last_year = df[df$Time_Difference > 0 & df$Time_Difference < 53, ]
  tmp_col_sum = colSums(df_last_year[ , cols_to_sum], na.rm = TRUE)
  return(tmp_col_sum)
}

#oddly you have to add days
df$Month_Date = paste0("01-", df$Month)
df$Month_Date = as.POSIXct(df$Month_Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")

#not worried about performance because the data set is not that large
dates = c("01-Jan-05", "01-Feb-05", "01-Mar-05")
res = data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(dates)){
  tmp = subset_last_year(df, dates[i])
  res = rbind(res, tmp)
}
rownames(res) = dates
colnames(res) = c("A", "B", "C")
```